# Can you print either the name of the boolean or the result of a parameter?

Tags: python

I'm supposed to be writing code for some games of chance, and I'm working on a coin toss game. I have this almost working completely but the only thing I'm still stuck on is printing what the actual coin flip was.

When someone bets I want the result to say either

> Winner winner, the coin landed on heads/tails!
>   You now have $n left to gamble.

or

> Ohh- tough luck. The coin landed on heads/tails, better luck next time!
>   You now have $n left to gamble.

where it keeps a running tally of the bets. I've tried it to print the result in two ways, I'll post the full current code and a snippet of the other way I tried. The best I can get is a result saying the coin landed on true/false or 1/2 and I can't figure out how to get the result I'm looking for!

Thanks in advance.

Full code:

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 2)
money = 100
heads = num == 1
tails = num == 2
# heads = num % 2 == 0
# tails = num % 2 == 1
#Write your game of chance functions here

def coin_flip(call, bet):
  global money
  win = heads and call == heads or tails and call == tails
  lose = heads and call == tails or tails and call == heads
  if win:
    money += bet
    print("Winner winner, the coin landed on " + str(num) + "!")
    print("You now have $" + str(money) + " left to gamble.")
  else:
    money += -bet
    print("Ohh- tough luck. The coin landed on " + str(num) +", better luck next time!")
    print("You now have $" + str(money) + " left to gamble.")



#Call your game of chance functions here

coin_flip(heads, 30)
```

This yields 1/2 as opposed to heads/tails

And with this change:

```
 if win:
    money += bet
    print("Winner winner, the coin landed on " + str(call) + "!")
    print("You now have $" + str(money) + " left to gamble.")
  else:
    money += -bet
    print("Ohh- tough luck. The coin landed on " + str(call) +", better luck next time!")
    print("You now have $" + str(money) + " left to gamble.")
```

I get that the coin flip is True/False.

I'm mostly sure I understand why these aren't giving me the result I want but I'm not sure what needs to be done to get what I *do* want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple dict

```
di = {1:"Heads",2:"Tails"}
```

Then,

```
print(di[num])
```

Comment: Ahh thank you. I was hoping it was simple I just hadn't learned yet - day 4 of learning python haha

Comment: No worries, we have all been there :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import random
money = 100
heads = 1
tails = 2
# heads = num % 2 == 0
# tails = num % 2 == 1
#Write your game of chance functions here

def coin_flip(call, bet):
  num = random.randint(1, 2)
  valArray = ["heads", "tails"]
  global money
  win = num == call
  lose = num != call
  if win:
    money += bet
    print("Winner winner, the coin landed on " + valArray[num-1] + "!")
    print("You now have $" + str(money) + " left to gamble.")
  else:
    money += -bet
    print("Ohh- tough luck. The coin landed on " + valArray[num-1] +", better luck next time!")
    print("You now have $" + str(money) + " left to gamble.")



#Call your game of chance functions here

coin_flip(heads, 30)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It's a lot more elegant, and I think will be helpful for the second game of chance in the lesson that I'm working on now